# Probability of n distinct eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

For a randomly generated $n$ by $n$ matrix, is the probability that it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues equal to $1$? I have a feeling it must be.

But, if that's the case, why do we concern ourselves so much with situations where such a matrix has repeated eigenvalues? Is it because such situations arise so often in the real world? And, if so, what is it about real-world problems that leads to such "rare" matrices?

Sorry if my question seems a bit vague, I just thought of it when looking over geometric/algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: You might make it less vague by saying what you mean by randomly generated.

Comment: I suppose I mean chosen uniformly at random from the set of all real (or complex) $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: there is no uniform distribution over all real (or complex) matrices.

Comment: To make this concrete, say all elements of $M$ are chosen independently from unit normal  distributions.  Then for example you can show for finite $n$  that almost surely all eigenvalues of $M$ are distinct.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That works perfectly.